# ES6: Import a module as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I use the following (ES5) code to currently import a module and call it as a function (where `...` represents some arguments):

```js
var rimraf = require("rimraf")
rimraf(...)
```

I would like to utilise ES6's `import` with my code so I have tried the following ways:

```js
import * as rimraf from "rimraf"
import rimraf from "rimraf"
```

These are the ways to `import` that I have read about in various places, however each time I attempt to call `rimraf(...)` I get the error `ReferenceError: rimraf is not defined`.

Apologies if I'm just being stupid, but what is the correct way to implement my `import`?

Comment: If your module is not a package in the /node_modules/ directory you need to specify the relative route of the module i.e. `import rimraf from './rimraf'`

Comment: `import rimraf from "rimraf"; rimraf(...);` should work fine.

Comment: My package is in the `node_modules` folder, see https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf.

Comment: yeah, it should work fine then

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesn't seem to...as in my question only the ES5 method works, I get the error when using the suggestion from @loganfsmyth.

Comment: I think we'd need a reproducible example somewhere then, since the code provided should work. You also haven't specified, but are you using Babel to compile the modules, or what?

Comment: The equivalent syntax of your first example is `import rimraf from 'rimraf'`, if that's what you're asking. I'm not sure how babel handles it, but I know the `--experimental-modules` flag handles it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support `import` syntax as of [v9.11.1](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). In order to use that you'd need to setup/use something like `babel`, `Typescript` to compile. Alternatively you can follow the instructions in the link above to enable experimental support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer – I am using Babel (so using full ES6). Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: The Question doesn't state you are using any pre-processor. If you are, as you say, we'll need something to duplicate with.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import it like this

```
import * as rimraf from "rimraf"
```

and then use it like this

```
rimraf.rimraf(dir)
```

For example,

```
const clean = async () => rimraf.rimraf(dir);
await clean();
```

I'm using `"rimraf": "^5.0.1"` and node `v17.6.0`